# How do you RedirectToAction() on a GET, not on a POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

I have a scenario where I would like to redirect the user while he is accessing a page (GET, not POST), and I would like to know how to do this in ASP.Net MVC.

Here is the scenario. I have a controller with a multi-step process wizard. It is possible, even if unlikely, that a user tries to access step 1 although he has already completed that step. In that case, I would like to redirect him to step 2.

Something like:

```
public ViewResult Step1(int? id)
{
    //Do some stuff and some checking here...
    if (step1done)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("RegisterStep2");
    }
}
```

However, this gives the following error, because RedirectToAction is meant to be used in the  ActionResult method:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult'

Can someone tell me how to fix this and have my ViewResult method (GET action) perform a redirection? Should I simply use Response.Redirect() just as in plain old ASP.Net, or is there a "more ASP.Net MVC" way to do this?

Comment: Just change return type to ActionResult, since you're not always returning a view.

Comment: You must also have a return statement after the if clause.

Comment: @TomasJansson Yes, thanks. This was just an over-simplified piece of code just to illustrate what I was doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your return type to [`ActionResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult.aspx), the base class for both `ViewResult` and `RedirectToRouteResult`.

```
public ActionResult Step1(int? id)
{
    //Do some stuff and some checking here...
    if (step1done)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("RegisterStep2");
    }

    // ...

    return View();
}
```

Comment: I did not know a GET action could return an ActionResult. I thought this was for POST actions only. I'll try that.

Answer (score 6):

Change `ViewResult` to `ActionResult`

```
public ActionResult Step1(int? id)
{
    //Do some stuff and some checking here...
    if (step1done)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("RegisterStep2");
    }
}
```

`ViewResult` derives from the `abstract` class `ActionResult`.